# Can I safely sell an Xbox 360 with XBLA games on the HDD?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

Or will the buyer be able to find all of my payment information and stuff?

Obviously, my personal gamertag has been deleted.

Answer (score 5):

If your Gamertag has been deleted, no one will be able to access any of your profile information (including payment information) or any of your downloaded games, as they are downloaded and are owned by that Gamertag.

Honestly you're better off just wiping the drive completely.

Comment: All digital content on 360 has 2 licences, 1 for the account and 1 for the console. If the games were first downloaded on that console it will carry the console license even if the original user account has been deleted.

If you've not done a "Licence Transfer" to move them to a different console then any new users will be able to play them.

This is just the software licensing though, they won't be able to access your account details.

I wouldn't think MS are keen on anyone selling with games intact though so definitely safer to clear down first.