# How can I access my copy of Minecraft from a new Xbox account?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I have purchased and downloaded Minecraft on my old account, and I had to make a new account (on the same Xbox 360 console).

However, now it want let me play the full version of Minecraft, only the trial - it's trying to charge me $19.99 even though I have purchased it on the other account.

Is there any way I can get my copy of Minecraft to the new account and play the full game instead of having to buy it again?

Comment: Which console are you using?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170584/can-i-safely-sell-an-xbox-360-with-xbla-games-on-the-hdd)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the content if your old account isn't currently signed in. You can only access the content if the account that purchased the content is signed in.

I did something similar with some DLC my friend had purchased on the same xbox. I signed in on their account, then signed in my account (at the same time), and I had access to the DLC.

Therefore, since the original account is not signed in, the xbox is reading that you (current profile) do not own this content.

EDIT: [Here is a similar answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/233197/73976) covering the requirements of the console and user licenses.

Comment: Not true, you get 2 licenses. 1 for the console and 1 for the user although it works a little different between 360 and X1, see [Xbox Live Usage Rules](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/Legal/Usage-Rules). There are a handful of exceptions where they suppress the console license but Minecraft definitely has both.

Comment: @PeteWiFi I do have an answer on another question explaining this as well, but I can't find it at the moment. I'll link it when I do.